# How to populate table column cells with ComboBox and observe?

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

My table view has 2 columns. The first one has the name of my object and the second i want to have a ComboBox with values from my object attribute list.

Any change to the ComboBox will change its selected attribute with the list element that is chosen by the user.

For example:

```
| Name          | Choices           |
|---------------|-------------------|
| Object 1 Name | Object 1 ComboBox |
| Object 2 Name | Object 2 ComboBox |
```

So far i've managed to populate the names but i'm stuck with the choices column.

**MyObject Model**:

```
public class MyObject {

    // Objects name is the filename
    private File file; 
    // Selection from the ComboBox that is populated with infoList elements
    private SomeInfo selectedInfo; 

    private List<SomeInfo > infoList;

    ... getter/setter
```

**Controller**:

```
@FXML
private TableView<MyObject> myObjectTableView;
@FXML
private TableColumn<MyObject, String> myObjectNameTableColumn, myObjectChoicesTableColumn;

private void populateTableView(List<MyObject> myObjectList) {
    ObservableList<MyObject> myObjectObservableList = FXCollections.observableList(myObjectList);
    myObjectTableView.setItems(myObjectObservableList);
    myObjectNameTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(c -> new SimpleStringProperty(c.getValue().getFile().getName()));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your `myObjectChoicesTableColumn` is wrong. You need

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<MyObject, List<SomeInfo>> myObjectChoicesTableColumn ;
```

Then your cell value factory can be

```
myObjectChoicesTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().getInfoList()));
```

and to display a combo box you need a cell factory:

```
myObjectChoicesTableColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {

    ComboBox<SomeInfo> combo ;

    TableCell<MyObject, List<SomeInfo>> cell = new TableCell<MyObject, List<SomeInfo>>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(List<SomeInfo> info, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(info, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                MyObject rowItem = myObjectTableView.getItems().get(getIndex());
                combo.getItems().setAll(info);
                combo.setValue(rowItem.getSelectedInfo());
                setGraphic(combo);
            }
        }
    };

    combo.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
        myObjectTableView.getItems().get(cell.getIndex()).setSelectedInfo(newValue));

    return cell ;
}
```

You might find it cleaner to refactor the model, so that you wrap the list and the selected item in a new class:

```
public class SelectableInfo {
    private final ObservableList<SomeInfo> infoList = FXCollections.observableArrayList() ;

    private SomeInfo selectedInfo ;

    public ObservableList<SomeInfo> getInfoList() {
        return infoList ;
    }

    public SomeInfo getSelectedInfo() {
        return selectedInfo ;
    }

    public void setSelectedInfo(SomeInfo info) {
        selectedInfo = info ;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MyObject {
    private File file ;
    private SelectableInfo selectableInfo ;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

Then you would have the simpler:

```
@FXML
private TableColumn<MyObject, SelectableInfo> myObjectChoicesTableColumn ;

myObjectChoicesTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> new SimpleObjectProperty<>(cellData.getValue().getSelectableInfo());

myObjectChoicesTableColumn.setCellFactory(col -> {
    ComboBox<SomeInfo> combo = new ComboBox<>();
    TableCell<MyObject, SelectableInfo> cell = new TableCell<MyObject, SelectableInfo>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(SelectableInfo info, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(info, empty) ;
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                combo.setItems(info.getInfoList());
                combo.setValue(info.getSelectedInfo());
                setGraphic(combo);
            }
        }
    };
    combo.valueProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> 
        cell.getItem().setSelectedInfo(newValue));
    return cell ;
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. See update for a slightly different approach.

Comment: James i don't understand how i could populate the infoList since there is no setter in your new example. Did you missed that or it's me who's missing something? :) 
(The selectable choices are given dynamically from another method)

Comment: @pror21 You are missing the obvious: `getSelectableInfo().getInfoList().add(...)` or `getSelectableInfo().getInfoList().addAll(...)` or `getSelectableInfo().getInfoList().setAll(...)` etc etc (`remove(...)`, `clear()`,...). The list is final, not unmodifiable.

Comment: ohh you're right. It seems i must rest a bit. Thanks again for everything!